# threading issue - reciever prints before sender

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out the threads in java and I'm trying to understand the output that I got. I created 3 classes : sender,receiver and messagebox.

I'm trying to send data via the messagebox from the sender to the reciever. 
When the sender send data it prints "sender put element".
Once the reciever got an element it prints "reciever got element"

The problem is that in the console I see that the reciver printed that he got the element before the sender printed that he sent it ..

Sender :

```
public class Sender implements Runnable {
    private MessageBox msgBox;

    public Sender(MessageBox m)
    {
        msgBox=m;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Sender");
        for(int i=0;i< 100;i++)
        {
            msgBox.put(i);
            System.out.println("Sender put element : " + i);
            try {
                long sleep_time = (long)(Math.random()*5000);
                //System.out.println("Sender going to sleep for " + sleep_time + " ms");
                Thread.sleep(sleep_time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver :

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable{

    private MessageBox<Integer>  msgBox;

    public Receiver(MessageBox<Integer>m)
    {
        msgBox = m;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Receiver");
        while(true)
        {
                int element = msgBox.get();
                System.out.println("Receiver got element : " + element);
            try
            {
                long sleep_time = (long)(Math.random()*5000);
                //System.out.println("Receiver going to sleep for " + sleep_time + " ms");
                Thread.sleep(sleep_time);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

MessageBox :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MessageBox<E> {

    private Queue<E> msgQ;

    public MessageBox()
    {
        msgQ = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public synchronized void put(E i)
    {
        msgQ.add(i);
        notify();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : notifying other threads...");

    }

    public synchronized E get()
    {
        if(msgQ.isEmpty())
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : waiting for new element..");
                notify();
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return msgQ.remove();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return msgQ.isEmpty();
    }


}
```

main :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        MessageBox msgBox = new MessageBox<Integer>();
        Sender sender = new Sender(msgBox);
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver(msgBox);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(sender);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(receiver);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();


    }
}
```

console :

```
Receiver : waiting for new element..
Sender : notifying other threads...
Receiver got element : 0
Sender put element : 0
....
```

In addition, do I need to set the Q in the messagebox volatile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok. The output you see can happen because insert into messageBox and printing the message is not atomic.

Your code in Sender can be intercepted like this:

```
  Sender Thread                              Receiver Thread

   msgBox.put(i);
                                             int element =  msgBox.get();
                                            System.out.println("Receiver got element : " + element);  
   System.out.println("Sender put element : " + i);
```

So after sender put element and before sender prints the message, the receiver is able to get the element and print the message first because it runs in another thread. It will not help to put the message before the sender put the elements into messageBox, because then it can be incosistent in another way: it prints the message that the element was added, but it doesn't have to be added acutally because of some exception.

If you really want to have ordered put/receive messages, you have to put that messages into MessogeBox method like this:

```
public synchronized void put(E i)
    {
        msgQ.add(i);
        System.out.println("Sender put element : " + i);
        notify();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : notifying other threads...");

    }



public synchronized E get()
{
    if(msgQ.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : waiting for new element..");
            notify();
            wait();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return msgQ.remove();
}
```

You don't have to set msgQ as volatile if you access msgQ only under synchronized lock. You have to set your isEmpty method as synchronized too and then you don't have to set msgQ as volatile. So fix your code like this:

```
  public synchronized boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return msgQ.isEmpty();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your print statment like this from then Sender class

```
msgBox.put(i);
System.out.println("Sender put element : " + i);
```

```
System.out.println("Sender put element : " + i);
msgBox.put(i);
```

Becaue in your case MessageBox put the value and suddenly Receiver got the message and print and then your print statmentent call`System.out.println("Sender put element : " + i);`.